Azure DevOps nuget package vulnerabilities
I have some legacy pipelines using VSBuild@1 - when run, I get a neat list of vulnerable nuget packages.
##[warning]Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1903: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' 2.1.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hxrm-9w7p-39cc
Project "E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.sln" (1) is building "E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj : warning NU1903: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http' 2.1.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hxrm-9w7p-39cc
##[warning]Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1903: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory' 8.0.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qj66-m88j-hmgj
E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj : warning NU1903: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory' 8.0.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qj66-m88j-hmgj
##[warning]Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1903: Package 'System.Formats.Asn1' 6.0.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-447r-wph3-92pm
E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj : warning NU1903: Package 'System.Formats.Asn1' 6.0.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-447r-wph3-92pm
##[warning]Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1903: Package 'System.Private.Uri' 4.3.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5f2m-466j-3848
E:\agent\_work\12\s\Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj : warning NU1903: Package 'System.Private.Uri' 4.3.0 has a known high severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5f2m-466j-3848
##[warning]Foo.Web\Foo.Web.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1902: Package 'System.Private.Uri' 4.3.0 has a known moderate severity vulnerability, https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x5qj-9vmx-7g6g

When I update to use DotNetCoreCLI@2, I don't get this info.
Ideally I'd like to break the build when vulnerable packages are present.

How about running dotnet list package --vulnerable in a separate task?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/auditing-packages#running-a-security-audit-with-restore
and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nugetaudit-2-0-elevating-security-and-trust-in-package-management/

Running 'dotnet list package --vulnerable' in a separate task is something I'm actually doing.  I was hoping to combine the build warning with '--property:WarningAsError=true' - to essentially treat warnings (such as these) as errors - and fail the build.
